# What are pros to update to the latest version of any browser which we use? in terms of security and memory use

Tags: windows-xp, browser

What are pros to update to the latest version of any browser which we use? in terms of security and memory use.

I don't need any new features even should i upgrade? Does it increases security? Does new version uses less memory.

Comment: Only you can know if you're working in a strict environment.

Comment: As Eight Days says - only you know your environment. I think you should clarify your situation if you want more complete answers. Tullo's answer will be true for most home users but different environments or uses can be broken by an upgrade; work functions for example.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, new versions of browsers will have increased stability, performance and security.

As an (outdated) example, take the transition from Internet Explorer 6 to IE 7:

- IE7 supports the .PNG image format, providing transparency effects and clearer images than JPEG compression; IE6 does not.
- IE7 runs JavaScript faster than IE6, meaning client-heavy applications such as Google's suite of web apps (or indeed any web page which responds to clicks without reloading the page) will run faster
- IE7 supports (most of) CSS 2.1, meaning that newer websites will render more accurately than under IE6
- Features such as tabbed browsing and the like
- And of course, you alter the statistics of identified browsers on the net, meaning that when web developers ask "Can we implement this cool feature that only works in the latest browser?" the answer can be "Yes, of course!"

Answer (score 1):

You should always upgrade to the latest browser version, if only for the sake of security. I always wait a few days after a major revision, in case the new version includes nasty bugs.

Comment: For basic home users I agree, but in a work environment it isn't uncommon for security updates to break internal browser based functions. Just be aware of that consideration before updating - especially if you are a freelancer/contractor/etc.